How to refresh DataGridview after selecting combo box value
The view contains multiple combo boxes that are populated with data from the database in one call.
After selecting the combo box value I want to update the GridView. For the first time, data in the GridView is displayed, but when the values ​​in the combo box are changed, the GridView does not refresh to the new values.
Used DropDownClosed event.
Only when I click on the DataGridView does the update occur
(How to refresh Gridview after selecting combo box value)
Thank you in advance.
DataGridView.Refresh(), DataGridView.Update() doesn't work
